# The instruction at X referenced memory at Y. The memory could not be written

Tags: windows-7, memory, operating-systems, virtual-memory, memory-management

[TFG (Total Files Gaurd)](https://www.ess-g.com/en/tfg) is a software that used in offices to protect client's data from thief by malware and users. It encrypt some types of files(Network's Admin selects which type he/she want to be protected) and then the software encrypt all that type files amd decrypt the file when user double click on it to open it, and after modifying, the software encrypt and store it on the hard disk again.(All process are done automatically).

OK, in our office, we installed this software on a lot of client. It works fine on almost all the systems. But for some clients,after restart, the following windows appears and nothing work. the only thing that user can do is shutting down his system! (and admin must delete it remotely)

[image]

My question:

What does this image say? What is going on? does this software make a fake `expolorer.exe` process? or is it an interface between OS and explorer process?
Does it want to write something in a protected part of memory?

Answer (score 1):

The memory at that location is most likely corrupt, or protected by another application on the system. Seeing as the systems are managed by a Network Admin, I would expect that the same software is installed on all system, and all system are of the same model/specification. In which case, the issue is most likely RAM corruption at that specific address.

What the image is saying, specifically, is that an instruction set on the CPU at the address ### tried to access a piece of RAM at the address ### but failed. It's like sending a piece of mail to the wrong address, and having it sent back to you unopened.

Answer (score 1):

> does this software make a fake expolorer.exe process?

Most likely no, since that wouldn't work when you open a file through another program's "File open" dialog. It probably operates as a file system filter + explorer plug-in (shell extension).

My suspicion is that this encryption software is not co-operating well with some other shell extension that's also on the "problem" system.

> Does it want to write something in a protected part of memory?

Maybe. You'll get the same error message if the address simply isn't defined in the process context. A classic example is address 0, which is never defined in a Windows process.

However, it is possible for memory pages to be protected for read-only access - this is commonly used for program constants. You'd get the same error if the process tried to write to such as you would if it tried to write to an undefined address.

The usual *underlying* reason for an error like this is that the address (0x600507da) is wrong. This in turn happens either because the memory location the program got it from contains the wrong contents, or else there's a bug in the code. (Actually, "the memory location the program got it from contains the wrong contents" would also likely be caused by a bug in whatever code stored it there.)

Note that this is not usually indicative of a problem with the actual RAM at location 0x600507da. The addresses shown are all virtual, not physical (RAM) addresses, and it's unpredictable from one run of a program to another, and even from one moment to another, how its virtual addresses get mapped to physical ones.

It might, though, be a problem with RAM *somewhere*. if the RAM is dropping bits, it is possible that the reason the code is looking at address 0x600507da is that it was supposed to be looking at (let us say) 0x600517da... that address having being read from somewhere else in RAM... but the RAM returned 0x600507da instead. But RAM errors are not very common. If it was a RAM error like this we would expect the errors to be "all over the place", since over time the same RAM location can be used for many different processes and virtual addresses over time.

It most certainly does *not* mean that the contents *of the indicated location*  (0x600507da) are "corrupt", i.e. having the wrong content prior to the write. A write to memory doesn't care one bit (pun intended) what the previous contents are.

We can also say with certainty that the issue is *not* that the location is "protected by another application on the system". It is a per-process virtual address and no other process on the system can have anything to say about it.